# Setting a variable to the name of a class and calling a function from that class

Tags: python

Is there a way to set a variable to a string, and then use that variable to call a function from a class with the same name of that variable?

For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def printer(self):
        print "Hello."

Bar = Foo()
var = 'Bar'
```

When I then try to call var.printer(), I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'printer'
```

Which makes sense, but is there any way to call a class function in that manner, by using a variable with the same name as the class?

The reason I want to do this is so that I can have a set of individual variables, be able to adjust those variables, and then combine them into a string and call a function from a class with the same name as the string. For example:

```
from random import randint    

x = 0
y = 0

class c00(object):
    def printname(self):
        print "c00"

class c01(object):
    def printname(self):
        print "c01"

choose_class = randint(0, 2)

if choose_class == 0:
    xstr = str(x)
    ystr = str(y)
    string = 'c' + xstr + ystr
    string.printname()

else:
    y += 1
    xstr = str(x)
    ystr = str(y)
    string = 'c' + xstr + ystr
    string.printname()
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to the "Bar" object from it's name as a string from the mapping returned by `locals` (or `globals` depending on where `Bar` is defined):

```
locals()['Bar'].printer()
```

As a bit of unsolicited advice, usually if you're doing this, it's best to put `'Bar'` in a dictionary explicitly in the first place rather than needing to rely on `locals`/`globals`/`vars`.

Comment: Why is it best to use a dictionary over `locals/globals/vars`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the objects into individual variables, put them into a dict:

```
chooser = {'c00': c00(), 'c01': c01()}
chooser['c' + xstr + ystr].printname()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem well, you have no need to do that, just use a list and `random.choice` instead:

```
class c00(object):
    def printname(self):
        print "c00" 

class c01(object):
    def printname(self):
        print "c01" 

classes = [c01, c00]

my_var = random.choice(classes)()
my_var.printname()
```